# Как сохранить событие при всей сессии пользователя?

Tags: javascript

Есть блок X

Мне нужно чтоб при нажатии на close блок удалялся и не показывался во время всей сессии пользователя

Как это сделать?

Comment: "<div class="name"><a class="close"></a></div>"

Answer (score 5):

Для этого есть [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Положить информацию в сессионное хранилище

```
sessionStorage.setItem('closed', true);
```

Получить информацию из сессионного хранилища

```
let isClosed = sessionStorage.getItem('closed');
```

Код из примера в сниппете не работает, т.к. тут на stackoverflow в сниппетах не работает localstorage sessionstorage итд

```js
const area = document.getElementById('area');

if (sessionStorage.getItem('hide_info')) {
  area.style.display = "none";
} else {
  document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', () => {
    area.style.display = "none";
    sessionStorage.setItem('hide_info', "true");
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="area">
  example
  <button id="close">x</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="info" class="block">
  <button id="close">Close block</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block {
   display: none;
}
.block-active {
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
const block = document.getElementById('info');
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('close');

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  block.classList.add('block-active'); // это покажет блок
});

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  block.classList.remove('block-active'); // это скроет блок
});
```